# Microsoft Access Press Enter to add record

Tags: database, ms-access, vba

I have a Form with Two Fields

1. Seller - (A Drop Down list which needs to be selected manually)
2. Order ID - Order ids which i would be using a barcode scanner to add.

Since i need to select the seller once and add alot of order ids i set the "Tab Stop" to "No" for the seller field so that it wont tab there again and again.

Now what i just want is that, since i have already selected the Seller, when i scan a barcode, the data should be entered in the database, and be ready for the next entry to be added with the same Seller Selected (unchanged) and the Order Id field selected for me to scan the barcode again.

PS: Barcode Working - It enters the Text String in any field selected and the barcode itself presses enter after. So if i can set a way that after pressing enter the data is added to the table that would also be helpful.

Comment: Please have in mind that SO is a code helping forum, not an application writing forum.

Comment: hey , i am not actually developing an application its just a form inside Ms-Access i just want to find a code/way, that will enable the form to be submitted whenever enter is pressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your scanner makes an `Enter`, you could try something like :

```
Private Sub OrderId_AfterUpdate()
    Me.Dirty = False                  'save record
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec     'goto new record
End Sub
```

Comment: Happy new year btw, it gave me an error-- the expression On Change you entered as the event property setting produced the following error: Overflow.
* The expression may not result in the name of a macro, the name of a user-defined function, or [Event Procedure].
* There may have been an error evaluating the function, event, or macro.

Comment: That was a referencing problem googled it and solved it and after that your code worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

If this is all you're going to use this form for and I'm assuming this is an unbound form, in the form's keypress event, you can do:

```
Private sub Form_keypress(keyascii as integer)

If keyascii = 13 then
   'Run your SQL that inserts data into      'table
End if

End Sub
```

Under your events tab, don't forget to set Key Preview property to "yes", if you don't, the solution above won't work.

Comment: That would trigger the event whenever `Enter` is pressed in the form. Not ideal I think.